# How do I use the current Angular 2 version from Git (with npm)?

Tags: git, angular

I am currently following Angular 2 development, which means that I am using dependencies such as

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
…
```

in `package.json`. Given that there are some helpful fixes in Git already I would like to install the most recent version (or some specific commit) from Git. **What is the easiest way to achieve this?**

It would be preferable to avoid having to build Angular locally, but if necessary this would be acceptable, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could reference angular cdn from your systemJs config.
something like:
    @angular:                   'https://npmcdn.com/angular2'

then removing the dependency from the package.json

there is an example in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ER0tf8fpGHZiuVWB7Q07?p=preview)

```
//map tells the System loader where to look for things
var  map = {
  'app':                        'app',
  '@angular':                   'https://npmcdn.com/@angular', // sufficient if we didn't pin the version
};
```

the version is specified in a variable but maybe there is something like /latest